# $R^G=k[s_1,s_2,s_3]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I had discussed this earlier but I wanted a better solution . My professor had hinted using integral extension and stuff. I don't want to use theorems on symmetric polynomials.

$K=k(x,y,z)$ be the field of fractions of the integral domain $R=k[x,y,z]$. Hence the field comes equipped with the automorphisms of $G=S_3$ by permuting $x,y$ and $z$.

I want to prove the following

1. $K^G=k(s_1,s_2,s_3)$
2. $R^G=k[s_1,s_2,s_3]$

For part 1, I was able to show using Artin's Theorem.
For part 2, I noticed that $R^G=\{f \in k[x,y,z] | \sigma(f)=f\}=R \cap K^G=k[x,y,z] \cap k(s_1,s_2,s_3)$

Now one inclusion is obvious, that is $k[s_1,s_2,s_3] \subset k[x,y,z] \cap k(s_1,s_2,s_3)$

Now consider an element in $ k[x,y,z] \cap k(s_1,s_2,s_3)$, since it belongs to $k(s_1,s_2,s_3)$, we can assume that element to be $f(s_1,s_2,s_3)=\frac{g_1(s_1,s_2,s_3)}{g_2(s_1,s_2,s_3)}$. But $f \in k[x,y,z]$ and hence $g_2=1$. Hence $f=g_1(s_1,s_2,s_3) \in k[s_1,s_2,s_3]$ and this proves $(2)$.

Is this correct?
in not, then can anyone tell me how to do this using integral extensions and stuffs?

Comment: In general you don't have $g_2=1$, as in $\frac{s_1s_2}{s_2}$. You could say that you will cancel common factors and that conclusion $g_2=1$ will be true. However, all the work is being hidden in that implication.

Comment: The condition of "I don't want to use theorems on symmetric polynomials." is strange to me. If I wanted to show anything in the proof of this is precisely the role of the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials, and perhaps even one of the algorithms that prove it. Why try to hide the very part that contains all the substance?

Comment: and note that this is a special case. why forcing me to kill a mosquito with a bazooka. Also in what sense this is strange when I want to learn something different from what is in 'every standard text'

Comment: Well, the obfuscation of part (1) in who knows which theorem of Artin, is what Vladimir Arnold called French mathematics. Part (2) is asking to prove the fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials. I would would just prove it. Specially because from it not only the statement is interesting, but many of its proofs give you methods to express symmetric polynomials in terms of the elementary ones.

Comment: Part (1) has the little obstacle that the numerator and denominator don't need to be symmetric. One little idea that overcomes this obstacle is useful. I would make it explicit, rather than hiding it in some theorem of Artin. If $r=\frac{p}{q}$ then $Q=\prod_{\sigma\in S_3\setminus}\sigma(q)$ is symmetric and we can write $r=\frac{p\prod_{\sigma\in S_3\setminus\{e\}}\sigma(q)}{Q}$. Since $p\prod_{\sigma\in S_3\setminus\{e\}}\sigma(q)=rQ\in R^G$, then by part (2) it is in $k[s_,s_2,s_3]$. So, both new numerator and denominators of $r$ are in $k[s_1,s_2,s_3]$.

Comment: @user85667 , You are correct that it might not be a polynomial in symmetric polynomials but when it belongs to k(s_1,s_2,s_3}, then it must be quotient of two polynomials in symmetric polynomials and hence I am writing it in that way.

Comment: That is I am saying that the numerator and denominator are polynomial in symmetric because it is an element of k(s_1,s_2,s_3)

Comment: Look at it this way. If at no point there is actual work being done, then the argument is either assuming what it needs to prove (it is circular) or it is just obfuscating the work.

Comment: But the thing is we already know that $k(x,y,z)^{S_3}=k(s_1, s_2, s_3)$ and it follows from Galois Theory only because $k$ is a field. So work is being done in the sense we applied Artin's Theorem and FTGT. And the question I originally asked is about a field. I couldn't have used when $k$ is not a field. When not a field we would have to use fundamental theorem of symmetric polynomials, but as I mentioned we are working in a field, so it is a special case. Right?